# Check status of a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, centos-5

I'm running CentOS 5.5 and have created an init script. The start of the script contains:

```
# Source function library.
if [ -f /etc/init.d/functions ]; then
        . /etc/init.d/functions
fi
```

The start bit works fine, but I'm having problems with the status and stop part:

```
status)
echo -n "Status of script: "
status "/bin/sh /path/to/script.sh"
RETVAL=$?
echo
;;
```

In PS AUX the command appears as "/bin/sh /path/to/script.sh" and I can see the PID. But when I run:

```
./my_init_script status
```

It says the script is not running. Should I be using the /bin/sh bit, or just the full script path, or just the script filename?

The stop part of the init script utilises "killproc". Again what command should I be using to successfully kill all occurrances of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's like the corresponding function on Ubuntu, you should omit the "/bin/sh" part.

```
status "$DAEMON"
```

You will probably want to use something like:

```
killproc -p "$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON"
```

Near the top of your script define those variables:

```
DAEMON="/path/to/yourscriptname.sh"
PIDFILE="/var/run/yourscriptname/yourscriptname.pid"
```

And, of course, you'll need to make sure that `/var/run/yourscriptname` exists.

Use the existing scripts in `/etc/init.d` as models for your script.

Comment: My status line reads just that and I've specified $DAEMON - it's what the start part uses (and works), though the full start command is: "nohup $DAEMON >> /path/to/logfile &" In PS AUX I can see the command running. Any ideas?

Comment: @reado: Try it with just the script name without the directory. I don't have a Centos/RH system to check it on at the moment. Are you starting your script with `sh`? What happens if you start it without it (use `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the script, `chmod +x` it and start it with `/path/to/scriptname`)? Does `status` work in that case? Have you compared your init script to existing ones?

Comment: I'm not actually using a PID file - it's my first time writing these things and thought I wouldn't need one. Should I have one? If so, how would I append that to the existing startup method? Is there a command I can run to grab the PID of a newly create process and write the output into a file of my choosing?

Comment: @reado: Like I said I don't have a Centos system available right now to check this stuff on and I recommend that you follow existing scripts as models. It may be that if you set the `PIDFILE` variable that `init` will do the right thing for you. You may also need a block of comments at the beginning of the file in a particular format. Again, existing scripts will show you the way.

Comment: Sorted!! I created the PID file functionality in my script, saved it into /var/run and modified both stop and status to use -p "$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON". Now both work! Thanks a lot, much appreciated! :-)